# Why is the database publishing wizard not accepting SSL certificates?

Tags: ssl

I'm using the database publishing wizard to synchronize my local SQL Server 2005 database with my GoDaddy hosting account. I've followed all their directions and haven't had an issue for several months now.

Recently when I attempt to connect and synchronize, I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Test failed
------------------------------
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship
for the SSL/TLS secure channel. (System.Web.Services)
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
(System)
------------------------------
```

GoDaddy has verified that they can connect to the database through the wizard using a machine that is not connected to their internal network.

I'm in the process of trying things from a different machine, but I've noticed lately that both IE and Firefox are having problems connecting to accounts that require SSL certificates, such as Google Analytics.

Is there something I'm missing that could be mucking up SSL connections in general on my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a corrupt `crypt32.dll` or another SSL dependency problem. I would do a full `CHKDSK` then run `sfc /scannow`.